# Replace period character (".") from an entire data.table column in R

Tags: r, gsub

I am trying to remove all the period characters (`.`) from a data.table using `gsub`. Unfortunately, it isn't working. How do you propperly express the pattern to describe the periods to then replace them by nothing?

My code:

```
dt[, Address := gsub(".", "", Address)]
```

Result:

```
head(dt$Address)
[1] "" "" "" "" "" ""
```

I'm guessing that when `pattern = "."` R thinks I'm refering to the entire content of the object in question. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just need to escape the period. Try:

```
dt[, Address := gsub("\\.", "", Address)]
```

Comment: Why do you need two escapes?